# How to make Thunderbird notify when a new message has been moved by a Gmail filter?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, email-filter

I've created several Gmail "filters" which move messages to its dedicated folders skipping the Gmail "Inbox". I read Gmail messages using Thunderbird IMAP.

Now, when a new message arrive to Gmail and the filter moves it to another folder (like "My family"), in Thunderbird I do not get any notification that there is a new message in "My family" folder. By notification, I mean a feature where Thunderbird makes the folder bold and writes the number of new messages in the brackets.

The only way to know if there is a new message is to open each individual folder and wait for its contents to refresh with the Gmail server.

How can I fix this? Can this be fixed at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you read your mail on Thunderbird and rarely use the Google web GUI, you might be better served (no pun intended) by using *Thunderbird mail filters*, rather than Google's. An advantage is that you can direct mail from multiple accounts (e.g. Yahoo, Mail.com) to one folder. Of course, the downside is that the rule must be implemented on *each* device on which you use Thunderbird.

Comment: I had those but had to switch to Gmail Filters as I am using its IMAP from several computers.

Comment: When you access mail via IMAP, it stays on the server. In Thunderbird, you can have **local** folders as well as those sitting on the GMail server, so each PC connecting to GMail would look in the Inbox and move items to its local folder. This requires having the same filters and folders created on each PC, though, and is admittedly not ideal.